# Adding Menu Button to a Pushed View Controller

Tags: swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using the **SWReveal library** for my side menu. How do I implement this menu on a view controller that is pushed from my main menu item?

[image: want to add menu to this VC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just kidding, I saw where the problem is, I just haven't renamed the push segue identifier to **sw_right**.